# Is there a better way to verify tokens across services in djangoREST using django-simple-jwt

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, microservices

I have two Django backends hosted differently, one is an authentication service(ServiceA) that handles everything auth including generating tokens using the djangorest-simple-jwt library. The other is a service for my business logic(ServiceB).
There is a route on the 'ServiceA' that verifies tokens which is *token/verify*. I currently verify tokens on 'ServiceB' before processing a request, by calling the *token/verify* on ServiceA which I think is not the optimal way to communicate between the two services. What better approach do you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [JWTTokenUserAuthentication](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/experimental_features.html)?

> This can facilitate developing single sign-on functionality between separately hosted Django apps which all share the same token secret key.